# Websites/Softwares for keeping memos

Tags: organizer-software

Often I find myself writing an email to myself whenever there is stuff to be memoed. It's not something that I'd prefer to write on a tablet or on paper because the memo can be quite lengthy and hard to write because for instance, they can contain a long HTML link. This is rather inconvenient and I was hoping to find other solutions for conveniently writing and keeping that memo online.

Preferably, something web based would be good but a light-weight software is fine too.

I'm not looking for anything big, just something that has simple features such as sort by subject,date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot organizer software: Microsoft Onenote, Evernote, Springpad.  Evernote is my choice.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) and save any Word documents or text files with basic notes in there- they would be accessible anywhere you have an internet connection.

Comment: Yeah.. this was an alternative I thought of but I was looking for something specifically designed for storing and keeping memo.

Comment: You could also use google drive, and use them as memos. Google drive supports local docs.

Answer (score 0):

If your phone has Mail, and supports IMAP, you can keep a message as a draft; this is what iOS notes does to sync with your desktop.

If you have iOS, Workflowy looks cool, an outline organizer.